# How do i update a textblock from a page with a button from another one?

Tags: c#, wpf

On `MainPage` I have a class that handles the currency in my game(swag) like this

```
public class Swag
{
    public static int swag = 0;

    public void Add(int a)
    {
         swag += a;
    }

    public void Reduce(int a)
    {
         swag -= a;
    }

    public int Get()
    {
        return swag;
    } 

}
```

And a textblock `SwagMeasurer` that shows the value of swag. In `MainPage` I have a frame that displays a character in the middle of the game and has a button to click on.That frame navigates to PlayPage where I have the button. When I click that button I want to increase `swag` which I did:

PlayPage:

```
private void Clicker_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Swag.swag += 1;     
}
```

The problem now is that I need to update the text on `SwagMeasurer` and I don't know how to trigger that event with the click event from the other page.can you help me?

Comment: I have answered your question on your other question (which seems like the same... [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319293/i-want-to-handle-a-clickbutton-event-from-another-page)). If you do not want to work with self made events, you could also create a static variable referencing on your button, than create an instance in your `MainWindow` class of your `PlayPage` class and subscribe to the [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the static reference!