# I want to handle a clickbutton event from another page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two pages MainPage and PlayPage.Inside MainPage I have a frame and a textblock and inside the frame I have Playpage. When I click a button from play page I change a variable but the textblock doesn't update. How do I do that?
Here is my code:

```
public class Swag 
{
    public static int swag = 0;

     public void Add(int a)
    {
         swag += a;
    }

    public void Reduce(int a)
    {
         swag -= a;
    }

    public int Get()
    {
        return swag;
    } 

}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(PlayPage));
        SwagMeasurer.Text = Convert.ToString(Swag.Get());
    }
}


    public sealed partial class PlayPage : Page
    {
        public PlayPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Clicker_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Swag.swag += 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Because you are simply not updating the textblock at the moment, You have to update the textblock each time the `swag` value has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Handling and Raising Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) should be your new friend!

### Swag :

```cs
public class Swag
{
    private static int _swag;

    public static void Add(int a)
    {
        _swag += a;

        OnUpdate?.Invoke(new SwagEventArgs(a));
        OnAddition?.Invoke(new SwagEventArgs(a));
    }

    public static void Reduce(int a)
    {
        _swag -= a;

        OnUpdate?.Invoke(new SwagEventArgs(a));
        OnSubtraction?.Invoke(new SwagEventArgs(a));
    }

    public static int Get()
    {
        return _swag;
    }

    public static event AddedValueEventHandler OnAddition;
    public static event SubtractedValueEventHandler OnSubtraction;
    public static event UpdatedValueEventHandler OnUpdate;

    public delegate void AddedValueEventHandler(SwagEventArgs e);
    public delegate void SubtractedValueEventHandler(SwagEventArgs e);
    public delegate void UpdatedValueEventHandler(SwagEventArgs e);
}
```

Keep in mind, that [privacy should be respected](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/01/understanding-c-why-make-thing.html)!

---

### PlayPage :

```cs
public partial class PlayPage : Page
{
    public PlayPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Clicker_Sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Swag.Reduce(1);
    }

    private void Clicker_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Swag.Add(1);
    }
}
```

Please note, that I have **added** a *subtraction* [Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

### MainWindow :

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyFrame.Navigate(new PlayPage());
        SwagMeasurer.Text = Convert.ToString(Swag.Get());

        Swag.OnAddition += Swag_Addition;
        Swag.OnSubtraction += Swag_OnSubtraction;
        Swag.OnUpdate += Swag_OnUpdate;
    }

    private void Swag_OnUpdate(SwagEventArgs e)
    {
        SwagMeasurer.Text = Convert.ToString(Swag.Get());
    }

    private void Swag_OnSubtraction(SwagEventArgs e)
    {
        LastMode.Text = "That's a negative";
    }

    private void Swag_Addition(SwagEventArgs e)
    {
        LastMode.Text = "That's a positive";
    }
}
```

`LastMode` is also a [TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx) (reprecenting if the user has dropped or raised his *skill* level).

---

### SwagEventArgs :

```cs
public class SwagEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SwagEventArgs(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public readonly int Value;
}
```

`SwagEventArgs` is going to be used to store information as [event data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It is telling me that  The type or namespace SwagEventArgs could not be found. What do I need to do in order to solve that(or learn)? I forgot to mention that the swag class is inside MainPage.

Comment: @RobertG. Yup - my fault. The class is now implement in the answer!